# Ionic 2 - How to use subscribe in custom methods other than calling service

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to get contact list details and try to evaluate it with internal logic. But I am able to get only one variable at any time the other one becomes undefined. I know it is due to async function but dont know how to implement subscribe/promise for custom methods as I am not able to assign the subscribe to it. Please see my code below.

```
getCallerAudio() {
    this.file.listDir("file:///storage/emulated/0/", 'myfolder').then((result) => {
        for (let file of result) {
            if (file.isDirectory == true && file.name != '.' && file.name != '..') {
                } else if (file.isFile == true) {
                let name = file.name // File name
                let path = file.fullPath // File path
                let file_size='' //file size
                let file_datetime= '' // file date time
                file.getMetadata(function (metadata) {
                    file_size = metadata.size; // Get file size
                    file_datetime = metadata.modificationTime;
                    this.getFileDetail={size:file_size,datetime:file_datetime}; // can't assign this global valiable
                    console.log(file_size,file_datetime); // function inside working fine
                })
                console.log(this.getFileDetail); // i can't access
                console.log(file_size,file_datetime); // function outside not working
            }
        }

    });
```

Please let me know how to get this.getFileDetail out side the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement promises like below

```
getFileDetails() : Promise<boolean> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
this.file.listDir("file:///storage/emulated/0/", 'myfolder').then((result) => {
        for (let file of result) {
            if (file.isDirectory == true && file.name != '.' && file.name != '..') {
                } else if (file.isFile == true) {
                let name = file.name // File name
                let path = file.fullPath // File path
                let file_size='' //file size
                let file_datetime= '' // file date time
                file.getMetadata(function (metadata) {
                    file_size = metadata.size; // Get file size
                    file_datetime = metadata.modificationTime;
                   let fileDetails ={size:file_size,datetime:file_datetime}; // can't assign this global valiable
                    console.log(file_size,file_datetime); // function inside working fine
                    resolve(fileDetails);
                })
                console.log(this.getFileDetail); // i can't access
                console.log(file_size,file_datetime); // function outside not working
            }
        }

    });

})

getCallerAudio(){
    this.getFileDetails().then(val => {
    this.getFileDetail = val;
    })
}
```